# Subtract specific value from a list (of numbers) by user input

Tags: python, list, math

I'm a begginer in Python and i'm trying to do a program when the user chooses a number from a list, then after you type by how you much want to reduce this chosed number and then print the list.

I know that using list[specific index], check if matches with user input and repeating over and over again would do the job, but would be so unoptimized (if there's a way to do this in a single line would be fine), I want to do something that automatically finds the the number of the list by the user input.

**Desired Output:**

```
[5, 10, 15, 20]
what number you want from the list?
> 15
by how much you want to subtract?
> 6
>> [5, 10, 9, 20]
```

**my code:**

```
list = [5, 10, 15, 20]
print(list)
number = int(input("what's the number you want from the list?"))

if number in list:
    print("by how much you want to subtract?")
    remove = int(input())
    list[number] = list[number] - remove
    print("Done It!")

else:
    print("not a valid number")

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the number from `list` using itself. You must access it using its index. In order to get the correct index, use  `list.index(number)`.

Now, do not shadow `list` by creating a variable of that name. If you need a variable to represent a list, call it something else such as `numList`. If you shadow (aka assign a new value to overwrite a variable which is already in use), you will not be able to use the list's constructor later on inside your application.

```
numList = [5, 10, 15, 20]
print(numList)
number = int(input("what's the number you want from the numList?"))

if number in numList:
    print("by how much you want to subtract?")
    remove = int(input())
    index = numList.index(number)
    numList[index] = numList[index] - remove
    print("Done It!")

else:
    print("not a valid number")

print(numList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [5, 10, 15, 20]

print(list)

number = int(input("what's the number you want from the list?"))

for i in list:
    if i == number:
        usr_input = int(input("How much to subtract? "))
        index = list.index(i)
        list[index] = i - usr_input
        print("Done")
        print(list)
```

i know it is not one line but i hope this helps